# Python iterate dictionary of lists, but lists indexes can change depending on the request

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have the following dictionary of lists:

```
{
    1: [
        [
            ["080822", "090822"],
            ["2325", "1250"],
            ["1055", "1505"],
            ["090822", "090822"],
            ["CPT", "AMS", "AMS", "BCN", "1"],
            ["KL", "598", "KL", "142"],
            ["1540"],
            ["1:55:00"],
        ],
        ["G", "L"],
        "29888.20",
        "15898.20",
    ],
    2: [
        [
            ["090822", "100822","110822"],
            ["2325", "1250","1150"],
            ["1055", "1505"],
            ["100822", "100822"],
            ["CPT", "AMS", "AMS", "BCN", "1"],
            ["KL", "598", "KL", "142"],
            ["1540"],
            ["1:55:00"],
        ],
        ["G", "L"],
        "29888.20",
        "15898.20",
    ]
}
```

I want a way in which I can loop the lists and extract the data, the catch is that it needs to be dynamic, the first key has two date values, where the second has three values.

I've tried the following:

```
report_rows = {}


if items_from_dict:
    report_rows['from'] = {}

    for flight, details in items_from_dict.items():
        
        total_amount = details[2]
        total_tax    = details[3]
        
        for item in details:
            
            try:
                n              = 2
                departure_date_1 = item[0][0]
                # print(item[0][1])
                if len(departure_date_1) > 4:
                    date_dd_mm_yy  = [departure_date_1[i:i+n] for i in range(0, len(departure_date_1), n)]
                    departure_date_1_f = DateFormatterFunc(date_dd_mm_yy[0],date_dd_mm_yy[1],date_dd_mm_yy[2])
                
                if not item[0][1]:
                    departure_date_2 = ''
                else:
                    departure_date_2 = item[0][1]
                    date_dd_mm_yy  = [departure_date_2[i:i+n] for i in range(0, len(departure_date_2), n)]
                    departure_date_2_f = DateFormatterFunc(date_dd_mm_yy[0],date_dd_mm_yy[1],date_dd_mm_yy[2])  
                
                departure_time = item[1][0]
                
                if len(departure_time) == 4:
                    dept_time_hh_mm         = [departure_time[i:i+n] for i in range(0, len(departure_time), n)]
                    departure_fomatted_time = dept_time_hh_mm[0] + ":" + dept_time_hh_mm[1] 
        
                arrival_time = item[2][0]
                
                if len(arrival_time) == 4:
                    arv_time_hh_mm = [arrival_time[i:i+n] for i in range(0, len(arrival_time), n)]
                    arrival_time_f = arv_time_hh_mm[0] + ":" + arv_time_hh_mm[1] 
            except IndexError:
                pass
            
            try:
                arrival_date = item[3][0]
                # print(arrival_date)
            except IndexError:
                pass
                
            try:
                flight_number = item[5]
                final_number_f = flight_number[0] + flight_number[1]
                # print(final_number_f)
            except IndexError:
                pass

    
        report_rows['from'][flight] = {
            'depature_time': departure_fomatted_time,
            'arrival_time': arrival_time_f,
            'departure_date_1': departure_date_1_f,
            'flight-number' : final_number_f,
            'total_amount': total_amount,
            'total_tax':total_tax
        }
```

The departure_date_1 will have the items : 080822, but I need it to have both the date values. I can achieve the result with a few if statements, but I feel it can be done in a lot less code. Thanks.

Current Output:

```
{'from': 
    {1: {'depature_time': '23:25', 'arrival_time': '10:55', 'departure_date_1': '2022-09-08', 'flight-number': 'KL598', 'total_amount': '29888.20', 'total_tax': '15898.20'}, 
    2: {'depature_time': '23:25', 'arrival_time': '10:55', 'departure_date_1': '2022-09-08' 'flight-number': 'KL598', 'total_amount': '29888.20', 'total_tax': '15898.20'}
    }
}
```

Desired Output:

```
{'from': 
    {1: {'depature_time': '23:25,12:50', 'arrival_time': '10:55,15:05', 'departure_date_1': '2022-09-08,2022-09-08', 'flight-number': 'KL598', 'total_amount': '29888.20', 'total_tax': '15898.20'}, 
    2: {'depature_time': '23:25,12:50,11:50', 'arrival_time': '10:55,15:05', 'departure_date_1': '2022-09-08' 'flight-number': 'KL598', 'total_amount': '29888.20', 'total_tax': '15898.20'}
    }
}
```

Comment: The values associated with keys *1* and *2* are identical in structure. Can you highlight where one value has two dates and the other three. Also, show required output

Comment: I've edited the question, I just need to be able to get all the values associated with each index and append it to the report_rows dictionary, split by comma or pipe. @Vlad

Comment: you can just use the `len()` function given that for each value in the dict all the lists are the same length....